# how to save a pandas dataframe into a sav file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, spss

I have the following `dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
mc_all = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [0,1,1,2],
'col_2' : ['france','france','uk','uk']})
```

I am trying this in order to save this `dataframe` into a `sav` file

```
args = ( list(mc_all.columns), dict(zip(list(mc_all.columns),[0]*len(list(mc_all.columns)))) )
with SavWriter('mc_all.sav',*args) as writer:
    writer.writerows(mc_all)
```

according to [this](https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/index.html) but it doesnt work. it throws an error:

> error.SPSSIOError: Problem committing header [SPSS_INVALID_HANDLE]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use pyreadstat:

```
import pyreadstat

pyreadstat.write_sav(mc_all, savFileName)
```

More information here:

https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat#writing-files

Answer (score 2):

`.writerows` can't take as input. You have to convert your dataframe to np.array to write it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mc_all = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [0,1,1,2],
                       'col_2' : ['france','france','uk','uk']})
savFileName = 'mc_all.sav'
args = (['col_1', 'col_2'], dict(col_1=0, col_2=0))
array = mc_all.values
with SavWriter(savFileName, *args) as writer:
    writer.writerows(array)
```

Comment: where is `SavWriter` imported from? I'm guessing it's this package : https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/#module-savReaderWriter , but you've not imported it. Why have you imported pandas and numpy but not savwriter? I feel i'm missing something obvious...